# RxJS forkJoin's http requests being cancelled by chrome

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I am facing an issue with RxJS's **forkJoin** operator and http requests being cancelled by chrome.

I have an array of observables (i.e. http requests) called `validationSupportBatch$`.

I am using the array as follows:

```
this.subscription.add(
  forkJoin<T>(validationSupportBatch$)
    .pipe(mergeMap(() => this.getByStandardActivityCode()))
    .subscribe((svs: T[]) => {
        this.validationSupports = svs;
        this.notificationService.success('SVS.SAVE.success');
      },
      error => this.notificationService.error('SVS.SAVE.failure')
    )
);
```

Unfortunately, the requests are cancelled by chrome (see screenshot below for a batch of 3 http requests).

[image: screenshot]

Can someone please help?

**edit**:

Here are the request headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer XXX
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: https://localhost:4200
Referer: https://localhost:4200/validation/applied/activity/HHN-KADJAR-A0000020/standard-validation-support?planId=HHN-KADJAR-I001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
x-validation-context: APPLIED
x-validation-project-family: HHN
x-validation-project-name: Kadjar
x-validation-project-scope: 39416543-6b07-4e92-afd5-afacb1f18975
```

and the request body (just json):

```
{"id":null,"nature":"PHYSICAL_POWERTRAIN","natureLabel":"Physical - Powertrain","numberOfDays":0,"requiredQty":2,"appliedActivity":{"code":"HHN-KADJAR-A0000020"}}
```

**edit 2**: Oddly enough, when I don't add the `forkJoin` to the `subscription`, the requests work fine. 
My code is now:

```
forkJoin<T>(validationSupportBatch$)
  .pipe(mergeMap(() => this.getByStandardActivityCode()))
  .subscribe((svs: T[]) => {
        this.validationSupports = svs;
        this.notificationService.success('SVS.SAVE.success');
      },
      error => this.notificationService.error('SVS.SAVE.failure')
 );
```

Notice the `this.subscription.add(` part has been removed.

Any idea why the `subscription` would prevent the requests to get through?

**edit 3**: Here is how I manage my subscriptions in my component:

```
export abstract class ValidationSupportListComponent<T, U> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  ...

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  saveValidationSupports(supports: T[]) {
    const validationSupportBatch$ = _(supports)
      .filter(support => support.requiredQty > 0)
      .flatMap(support => _.times(support.requiredQty, () => this.saveValidationSupport(support)))
      .value();

    this.subscription.add(
      forkJoin<T>(validationSupportBatch$)
        .pipe(mergeMap(() => this.getByStandardActivityCode()))
        .subscribe((svs: T[]) => {
            this.validationSupports = svs;
            this.notificationService.success('SVS.SAVE.success');
          },
          error => this.notificationService.error('SVS.SAVE.failure')
        )
    );
  }
```

**edit 4**: I am realizing that other uses of `this.subscription.add(` within the component do not work either...

See for example. Following code results in a **cancelled** request:

```
  this.subscription.add(
    this.deleteValidationSupport(entity)
      .subscribe(() => this.removeFromModel(entity))
  );
```

Comment: Just curious.. May I know what does `add()` do? Somehow I have not had to chance to use that particular RxJS's operator

Comment: Hi @wentjun. Here is the documentation link: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subscription#add

Comment: Would you please post the log of your console too ?

Comment: Hello @trichetriche. There are no errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: Do other requests go through ? What if you make a single request instead of using `forkJoin` ? Do GET requests work too ? Do you have any CORS extensions that would prevent your requests from going through ? Are you sure you don't have any logs, or did you simply filter it ? Don't you have anymore information in your console when you set it to verbose ?

Comment: @trichetriche Let me come back to you about the logs. Bear with me.

Comment: @trichetriche. Yes other requests get through. By enabling the network logs, I do get this log: `XHR failed loading: POST "https://localhost:4200/api/pval/plan/activity/applied/validationsupport"`

Comment: Ok, could you please provide the request's payload ? Notably the request headers

Comment: One quick question: can a cancelled request issue be related to the backend?

Comment: What do you do with `this.subscription`? Do you maybe unsubscribe and thereby cancel the requests manually?

Comment: @fridoo I have edited my post to show how I manage subscriptions. Please note that I don't cancel my requests manually.

Comment: And are you sure that the component isn't destroyed right after you send the requests with `forkJoin`?

Comment: @fridoo: I have added a log in the `ngOnDestroy`. I can confirm the component is not destroyed.

Comment: I have added an answer to my post. A careless copy & paste was the cause of the issue. Thanks a lot all for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.

In one of the sub classes of the component, I had the following issue in my code:

```
  this.subscription = this.planService
    .get(this.planId)
    .subscribe(plan => (this.direction = plan.direction));
```

which reassigned the instance of the **`subscription`**. Hence the cancelled requests...

Comment: You should consider using takeUntil operator for unsubscribing from observables, this comes from real power of rxjs, 

this.planService.get(this.planId).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next(true);
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }